# Pass Parameters from SignedOut Stack to SignedIn Stack

Tags: react-native, authentication, navigation, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm having trouble with deep linking, specifically when it comes to being able to render a specific screen inside my stack for signed in screens. I want the deep link to pop up a screen that will let me add a contact to the user's contact list, and then will navigate back to home. However, the deep link will only link to screens that are in the `SignedOut` stack, since the `signedIn` state variable is false by default. This is my App.js:

```
export default function App({ navigation, route }) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [wallet, setWallet] = useState(null);
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);
    const w = { wallet, setWallet };
    const u = { user, setUser };
    const a = { auth, setAuth };
    const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function set() {
            const s = await isSignedIn();
            setSignedIn(s);
        }
        set();
    }, [auth]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function get() {
            if (wallet === null) {
                const found = await getConnectedWallet();
                if (found !== null) setWallet(found);
            }
        }
        get();
    }, [auth]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function get() {
            console.log("Set user was called!");
            if (user === null) {
                const found = await getUser();
                console.log("Found user: ", found);
                if (found !== null) {
                    console.log("Set user!");
                    setUser(found);
                }
            }
        }
        get();
    }, [auth, user]);
    const linking = {
        prefixes: ["myapp://"],
        config: {
            screens: {
                
                SignedOut: {
                    screens: {
                        AddConnection: {
                            path: "adduser/:address/:name/:command?",
                            parse: {
                                address: (address) => `${address}`,
                                command: (command) => `${command}`,
                                name: (name) => `${name}`,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                Settings: {
                    path: "settings",
                },
            },
        },
        getStateFromPath(path, options) {
            const state = getStateFromPath(path, options);
            const newState = {
                ...state,
                routes: state.routes.map((route) => {
                    const p = route.params;
                    if (p.command) {
                        const { command, ...withoutScreen } = p;
                        if (command === "a") {
                            return {
                                ...route,
                                params: {
                                    info: withoutScreen,
                                    next: "AddNewUser",
                                },
                            };
                        } else
                            return {
                                ...route,
                                params: {
                                    info: "nothing to see here",
                                },
                            };
                    }
                }),
            };
            return newState;
        },
    };
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={a}>
            <UserContext.Provider value={u}>
                <WalletContext.Provider value={w}>
                    <NavigationContainer
                        linking={linking}
                        ref={navigationRef}
                        fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}
                    >
                        <Stack.Navigator>
                            {!signedIn ? (
                                <Stack.Screen
                                    name="SignedOut"
                                    component={SignedOutScreens}
                                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <Stack.Screen
                                    name="SignedIn"
                                    component={SignedInScreens}
                                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                                />
                            )}
                        </Stack.Navigator>
                    </NavigationContainer>
                </WalletContext.Provider>
            </UserContext.Provider>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

The deep link for `myapp://adduser/address/name/a` will only let me navigate to a screen in the `SignedOut` stack as I previously stated, but the annoying thing is that it will automatically authenticate once the splash screen renders, so everything needs to be done in `getStateFromPath`, but that function will only set the state inside the `SignedOut` stack, and the `route.params` will not transfer over once the authentication state changes. I'm a little lost, and feel like I'm missing a big concept, because it shouldn't be this difficult to do this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

```
// Introduce a "maybe signed in" state, in this case `null`
const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(null);



// In render, wait for signedIn to be resolved ...
            <Stack.Navigator>
              {signedIn === null 
              ? <Text>Loading...</Text> 
              : !signedIn ? (
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="SignedOut"
                  component={SignedOutScreens}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
              ) // ....
```